# Or in IF statement not working properly

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have this Or condition in an IF statement (in a foreach loop) in a Windows Form C# program:

```
if ((splittedFile.Count() != 3) || (splittedFile.Count() != 4)) 
    continue;
```

and it always does `continue`, even if `splittedFile.Count()` is 3 or 4.
The thing is that if I remove the Or condition:

```
if ((splittedFile.Count() != 4))
    continue;
```

it works properly!! Any ideas why?

Comment: There is no way for that to evaluate to false. If `splittedFile.Count() == 3` then `splittedFile.Count() != 4` and vice versa.

Comment: 8 am on monday morning :)

Comment: ahahahah that's right @CalvinSmith

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct behavior, you need to use `&&`.

The reason is that the count is fixed number, let's say *n*. Now the condition reads:

> *n* is not 3 or *n* is not 4.

Given *n* is 4, this means it is not 3, thus the test succeeds and vice versa.

A compiler can't detect this is trivially true, because between the two `if` statements, the `Count()` might change (for instance in a *multithreading* setting where the second thread would add/remove something to/from the collection). I agree however some analysis tools could be capable in some conditions to detect such trivial behavior. In general however such analysis can't be implemented because of *Rice's theorem*.

If you use `&&`, the expression reads:

> *n* is not 3 **and** *n* is not 4.

Thus both conditions should be true. In other words only if *n* is less than three and greater than 4, the condition holds.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
if ((splittedFile.Count() != 3) && (splittedFile.Count() != 4)) 
    continue;
```

I know `||` sound logical because : `if splittedFile.count is not 3 OR it is not 4 then continue;` But because there are 2 NOT `!` operators in the if expression an AND `&&` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

put a real number into your expression:

```
if( 3 != 3 || 3 != 4)
```

which is

```
if( false || true )
```

your expression will always be true, as `splittedFile.Count()` is always `(not 3) or (not 4)`

you want to `&&` your results together, which looks like

`(x != 3) || (x != 4)`

or

`!( x == 3 || x == 4)`

Answer (score 1):

Because one of your expressions will be *always* `true`. That's why `true || something` *always* returns `true`.

Let's analyze your `splittedFile.Count()` is `3`, `4` and other than these values.

- For `3`, your expression will be `false || true` and this returns `true`.
- For `4`, your expression will be `true || false` and this returns `true`.
- For other than `3` or `4`, your expression will be `true || true` and this returns `true`.

Strongly suspect you are looking for [`&&` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) which provides [logical-AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AND_gate).